# Ubuntu chooses wrong wireless driver in my notebook

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, xubuntu, lubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu 14.06 on a new notebook. Wireless worked during installation, downloaded updates, etc. but I have no connection now. Tried Lubuntu earlier and same thing. Apparently the driver is not properly recognised, according to lshw:

> broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic
>   firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless-IEEE 802.11

But I know from the vendor's site that my notebook uses an Intel Wireless WiFi 5100AGN card. How can I make Xubuntu to recognise and use the proper driver for Intel?

The output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is void.

Please, is there something that can be done? The netbook is useless without an internet connection.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.